# Recoger datos de una variable php y mostrarla en HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress, plugin

He creado un plugin muy simple en wordpress pero que hace su función, necesitaba una forma de leer los datos de un formulario y que los comparase con los de una tabla en la base de datos de wordpress (la tabla nikkiclub), en la que estan todos los datos de los usuarios, los cuales tienen un numero de tarjeta y una clave, y me devuelve el saldo total de ese usuario, hasta hay sin problema, use la clase que ofrece WordPress ($wpdb).

Mi problema viene cuando quiero mostrar el dato, tal y como me lo tengo me muestra el dato por un echo, pero claro me aparece en la parte superior izquierdeada y quiero que se muestre en el custom html que me he creado. Pero no se como hacer que el custom html me acepte el código php del plugin ya que al introducirlo la parte de get_results en adelante no lo coge como código php creo que es por el simbolo "->" que me exige poner el $wpdb.
Al pasarme esto no puedo tener el php y el html en el mismo sitio.

He pensado en usar una base de datos externa, pero no se bien como conectarme desde wordpress a una base de datos externa, y supongo que tendría el mismo problema.

Espero que me podais ayudar a visualizar la variable en php del plugin en mi custom html. Gracias de antemano.

Codigo PHP:

```
$NumTarjetaFidelizacion = $_POST['NumTarjetaFidelizacion'];

$ClaveTarjeta = $_POST['ClaveTarjeta'];

global $wpdb;

$registros = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM nikkiclub WHERE numerotarjeta='$NumTarjetaFidelizacion' AND Clavetarjeta='$ClaveTarjeta'" );

?>

Custom HTML:

<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="NumTarjetaFidelizacion" required="">
<input type="text" name="ClaveTarjeta" required="">
<input type="submit" value="Consultar">
</form>
```

Comment: Creo que no se entiende bien la explicación respecto al trozo de código que muestras, te sugiero que añadas un título con el nombre de los ficheros implicados y el código (html, php o ambos) que contiene, así como el `echo`que dices que si funciona.  Quizá la utilización de un [shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) te facilite la integración de datos y html.

Answer (score 0):

Como bien me han dicho he creado un shortcode que me consultaba los datos me los mostraba, y ya puestos me hacia un formulario para mostrarlos.

```
add_shortcode('compDatos', 'comprobarDatos');
function comprobarDatos(){
$NumTarjetaFidelizacion = $_POST['NumTarjetaFidelizacion'];
$ClaveTarjeta = $_POST['ClaveTarjeta'];
global $wpdb;
$datos = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM nikkiclub WHERE numerotarjeta='$NumTarjetaFidelizacion' AND Clavetarjeta='$ClaveTarjeta'" ));
$mostrarDatos='
<div><h3>Datos del primer titular</h3></div>
<form method="post">
<div>Nombre: <input type="text" name="nombretutor1" value=' .$datos[0]->nombretutor1. '> Apellidos: <input type="text" name="apellidostutor1" value=' .$datos[0]->apellidostutor1. '>DNI: <input type="text" name="dnitutor1" value=' .$datos[0]->dnitutor1. '></div>
<input type="submit" value="Modificar" >
</form>';
return $mostrarDatos;
}
```